# How do I add a class to qp_nav_menu <a> tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, navigation

So I've been beating myself up over this for two days. I just need to add the bootstrap "nav-link" class to my  tags withing wp_nav_menu. Here is what I've currently got.

> header.php

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'my-custom-menu',
    'menu'            => 'my-custom-menu',
    'container'       => false,
    'container_class' => false,
    'container_id'    => false,
    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
    'menu_id'         => false,
    'depth'           => 0,
) );
?>
```

> functions.php

```
//Load Custom Menu Navigation
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'my-custom-menu', __( 'My Custom Menu' ) );
}

//Clean up Custom Menu by Removing Unecessary Tags
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1 );
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1 );
add_action( 'init', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter' );
function wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter( $var ) {
    return is_array( $var ) ? array_intersect( $var, array( 'current-menu-item' ) ) : '';
}

//Remove Unecessary <li> Classes
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_nav_menu_css_class' );
function my_nav_menu_css_class( $classes ) {
    $custom_classes = array();

    foreach ( $classes as $class ) {

        if ( $class == 'menu-item' ) {
            return $custom_classes;
        }
        $custom_classes[] = $class;
    }
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'custom_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 4 );
function custom_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'my-custom-menu' ) {

        $class = "nav";

        // Make sure not to overwrite any existing classes
        $atts['class'] = ( ! empty( $atts['class'] ) ) ? $atts['class'] . ' ' . $class : $class;
    }

    return $atts;
}
```

Here is the current output I'm getting with an error code:

> Output

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul id="menu-main-navigation-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-auto"><li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://localhost/test-article/" aria-current="page" class="nav-link">Test Article</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the error I'm receiving. I only get this error when trying to pass the `nav-link` class to the tag. If I change it to anything other class it works fine. I have a feeling there is some conflict in bootstrap.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on
>   'Document': 'http://localhost/' is not a valid selector.

So this is where I'm at, if there is more information needed or if I'm being to vague please let me know and I'll update as necessary, TIA!

Below is a similar outcome that I'm looking for:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#top">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So here was the solution. There is a chunk of code in my bootstrap.min.js file that reflected the following.

```
document.querySelector(e)?e:null}
```

Changing to the following fixed it for me

```
document.querySelector("[e]")?e:null}
```

Comment: So I have found the solution on my own. I edited the above with my solution, it ended up being an error in my bootstrap.min.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function add_class_anchor_nav($atts, $item, $args)
{
    // check if the item is in the primary menu
    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        // add the class
        $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_anchor_nav', 10, 3);
```

Comment: I still get the same error from my example above. "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'http://localhost/' is not a valid selector."